# My bootstrap modal has an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'hide') at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> when used

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap modal does not work on a specific page but works well in another page. When I click the Profile It only shows this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'hide')     at HTMLAnchorElement.

Here is the code:

```
 <div id="settings-dropdown" class="dropdown-content1">
        <div class="profile-name-container" id="mobile">
           <div><a class="profile-name"><?php echo $_SESSION['firstName']; ?></a></div>
           <div><a class="profile-role"><?php echo $_SESSION['role']; ?></a></div>
           <hr>
        </div>

    <a class="profile-hover" href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#viewModal" >
        <i class="bi bi-person profile-icons"></i>Profile
    </a>
    <a class="profile-hover" href="#" id="logoutBtn">
        <i class="bi bi-box-arrow-left "></i>Logout
    </a>
</div>
```

I have tried changing the bootstrap versions, changing order of the scripts etc. and still no clue why does this occur.

Comment: Please provide the code for your modal, which should exist on the same page.

Comment: And it would be best if you'd extract PHP from this question, as it's not relevant. Bootstrap is a frontend technology, so show us rendered HTML (or a representative example). Also tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Protip: "Logout" is a noun. Your button should read "Log out", which is a verb.